# How to play a sequence after the other?

Tags: coronasdk

I declared two sequences like this:

```
*rest of code for sprite sheet already written above*  
sprite.add(sprite1,"eyes",1,7,500,1)   
sprite.add(sprite1,"ears",8,13,500,1)  
local instance = sprite.newSprite(sprite1)  
instance.x = display.contentWidth/2  
instance.y = display.contentHeight/2
```

Then I tried playing them like this with some delay between each of them:

```
local function move1()  
instance:prepare("eyes")  
instance:play()  
end

local function move2()  
instance:prepare("tails")  
instance:play()  
end

timer.performWithDelay(1000,move1,1)  
timer.performWithDelay(2000,move2,1)
```

But that doesn't work because once the second function is called, the sprite is displaced from its original position. In other words, it disappears for a few seconds. Initially, I thought it tried to play both of the sequences at once, but then, I set it to only loop once and it's still giving me this problem. Anyone knows how I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/spriteinstanceaddeventlistener